AsyncClient for a Binance Trading Bot explanation?
Good morning,
I´m learning the introduction of algorithmic trading in Binance with the python-binance package and it is the first time I start with asynchronous programming.
I have created a simple_bot() function that makes a buy when having the pair BTCUSDT divsible by 10 at market price.
I have tried to understand the following main() code but I cannot comprehend why:

We need to use await for the client object rather than the other first three lines.
Why do we need to use async in the definition of main().
Why do we need to use async in the section with ts as tscm: I have a bit of idea here and I think that it is to have the while loop executing and using simple_bot() at the same time.

Here I provide the code that I have been using:
from binance import BinanceSocketManager, AsyncClient
import asyncio

stop_streaming = False #Seting a stop streaming variable (initially:False)

def simple_bot(msg):
    '''Define how to process incoming WebSocket messages'''

    time = pd.to_datetime(msg["E"], unit = "ms")
    price = float(msg["c"])

    print("Time: {} | Price: {}".format(time, price))

    if int(price) % 10 == 0:
        order = client.create_order(symbol = "BTCUSDT", side = "BUY", type = "MARKET", quantity = 0.1)
        print("\n" + 50 * "-")
        print("Buy {} BTC for {} USDT".format(order["executedQty"], order["cummulativeQuoteQty"]))
        print(50 * "-" + "\n")

        global stop_streaming
        stop_streaming=True


# PROBLEM HERE

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bm.symbol_miniticker_socket(symbol = "BTCUSDT")

    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            simple_bot(res)

            if stop_streaming:
                break

    await client.close_connection()

await main()

I understand that the while loop is to remain doing calls to simple_bot() until the condition is met, and the client part is to connect to binance. Is just the asynchronic part of the code that is giving me problems.
